# Touch Events stop working on iPad after the Video tag

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, video, touch

I have an application that lets you swipe left and right to view different screens, or alternatively click on the Next and Previous buttons to navigate.

```
if(isMobile){
    detectSwipe = true;
    document.addEventListener('touchstart',TouchStart,false);
    document.addEventListener('touchmove',TouchMove,false);
    document.addEventListener('touchend',TouchEnd,false);
    document.addEventListener('touchend',TouchCancel,false);
}

$("#prevBtn").on('touchstart click', function () { 
    ...
}
```

The problem is for some unknown reason when it reaches a screen with a video tag all buttons become unclickable and only the swipe events are still active. This only happens on the iPad however, on the desktop it works fine.

```
<video width="960" height="560">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg"/>
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm"/>
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I've also tried to use a embed youtube video instead of the video tag, but the problem persists.

Comment: Can u post a fiddle if possible...

Comment: Sadly no, the full thing is over 14000 lines of code

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the video element's controls to `false` and set your own controls, for it to work.

Comment: Sadly that wasn't an option. I had to use the default controls